# Accessing html files on server via webView

Tags: android, html, webview

I am trying to access the HTML files stored on a server via webView. Have tried these lines of code but it does not show the content.

//webView.loadUrl("file://///server2/panquest//index.html");

//webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://///server2/panquest/index/", "html", "text/html",  "utf-8",  "");

// webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://///server2/panquest//index.html");

How can go about this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is this server?

Answer (score 0):

Your Android device does not have direct access to filesystems outside of the device.

Use an `http:` URL to access an HTTP server. If your server is not an HTTP server, then you need to fix your server.